# Changing the unit movement of a JSlider

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

I suppose this is a very silly question but I cannot figure out the solution/how to ask this to google. Basically, I want that my JSlider changes every X units each time an user clicks on it instead of 1 unit. How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's what I did in one of my apps... suppose it was `setMinorTickSpacing()`and `setMajorTickSpacing()`:

```
JSlider jSlider1 = new JSlider();
jSlider1.setMajorTickSpacing(50);
jSlider1.setMaximum(500);
jSlider1.setMinimum(100);
jSlider1.setMinorTickSpacing(50);
jSlider1.setPaintLabels(true);
jSlider1.setPaintTicks(true);
jSlider1.setSnapToTicks(true);
```

Comment: The key is actually this line: `jSlider1.setSnapToTicks(true);` which forces movement by minor tick degrees. 1+

Comment: Finally! I had maximums, minimums and ticks spacings similar to you but snaptoticks was false. Thanks!

Comment: @Learningfrommasters: if this answer helped, then consider accepting it

Comment: Yep, in 6 minutes when Stackoverflow let me do it!

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the other answer, you need to

1. set the minor tick spacing to how ever much you want it to move
2. set the `setSnapToTicks(true)` so that the slider by default moves minor tick increments

e.g.,

```
final JSlider slider = new JSlider(0, 100, 50);
slider.setMinorTickSpacing(5);
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(20);
slider.setPaintTicks(true);
slider.setPaintLabels(true);
slider.setSnapToTicks(true);

slider.addChangeListener(ce -> {
    System.out.println("value: " + slider.getValue());
});

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, slider);
```